# UFPDF russian characters do not show up, php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am using UFPDF. Trying to out put on pdf file russian characters. But instead I'm getting:

```
Ð–ÐμÐ»ÐμÐ·Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‡ÐμÐ»Ð¾Ð²ÐμÐº. Ð‘Ð¾Ð»ÑOEÑˆÐ°Ñ•
```

UFPDF - converts all text is in UTF-8. I checked mb_detect_encoding and yes the string is in UTF-8.

I am getting the data from mysql database and outputting it to pdf file. The mysql table is in utf8_general_ci.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: I have not tested the library UFPDF, but I am quite sure Russian characters would show up fine if you would use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/). See a [PDF example with different languages](http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_utf8.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I found free php library to generate and display russian characters in a pdf document.

```
tfpdf.php
```

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: Helped me a lot, dude. Tried lot of others libraries.